# Find internal views of a dynamically created fragment

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments, fragmentmanager

I have dynamically added a fragment to another fragment.

I need to find a few views within that fragment.

How do I achieve that?

here is my code:

```
@Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_educational, container, false);

        if (view != null)
        {
            ButterKnife.inject(this, view);
        }


        DisposableEducationalFragment disposableEducationalFragment = new DisposableEducationalFragment();
        getChildFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.fragmentContainer,disposableEducationalFragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
```

I want to find these views within that Dynamic fragment:

```
howItWorks = (RelativeLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.HowItWorks);
            howWeHelp = (RelativeLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.HowWeHelp);
            knowYourBloodPressure = (RelativeLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.KnowYourBloodPressure);
            learnAboutBirthControl = (RelativeLayout) fragmentView.findViewById(R.id.LearnAboutBirthControl);
```

Answer (score 0):

So, save `View view` into a temp variable and call it later.

`tmpView = view;`

and somewhere later:

`howItWorks = (RelativeLayout) tempView.findViewById(R.id.HowItWorks);`

or , may be, just try it:

`howItWorks = (RelativeLayout) getActivity().findViewById(R.id.HowItWorks);`